# How to add stops per vehicle in SUMO , project_flow

Tags: sumo, flow-project

I want to add a custom stop for a vehicle, with custom duration time, but the vehicle don't wait the specified duration at the stops

I'm trying to use the function 'setStop' from traci/_vehicle.
i defined duration and when that didn't work, i tried adding the 'until' parameter.

this is the related documentation i am referencing

https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Definition_of_Vehicles,_Vehicle_Types,_and_Routes.html#stops

i expected the vehicle to reach the specified stop location and hold there for the specified duration. 
but the vehicle arrives at the location, stops, and immidiatly starts accelerating again with 0 time waiting

Answer (score 1):

found out my problem, the issue was with the acceleration_controller which would cause the vehicles to ignore the stops assigned to them